# how to reach a class's property in LINQ

Tags: c#, database, linq, lambda

I am trying to find unread messages count with linq. I am counting if message's lastmodified date greater than user's LastViewedOn date. My ConversationMembers class has LastViewedOn property. But i couldn't find a way to reach users's LastViewedOn property..

```
.Count(x => x.ConversationMembers
            .Where(y => y.MembershipId.Value == membershipId)
            .Any(y => y.LastViewedOn == null)
            ||
            x.ConversationMessages.OrderByDescending(message => message.LastModifiedOn)
        .Any(z => z.LastModifiedOn > x.ConversationMembers
        .Where(y => y.MembershipId.Value == membershipId) 
        .Select()
        .LastViewedOn.Value
    )); //here i m trying to reach LastViewedOn value but it not work
```

Please can you help me about how can i reach that value?

Here my ConversationMember class

```
public class ConversationMember
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid ConversationId { get; set; }
    public virtual Conversation Conversation { get; set; }
    public Guid? MembershipId { get; set; }
    public DateTime? LastViewedOn { get; set; }
}
```

here ConversationMessage class

```
 public class ConversationMessage
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public Guid ConversationId { get; set; }
        public virtual Conversation Conversation { get; set; }
        public Guid? MembershipId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Column(TypeName = "datetime2")]
        public DateTime LastModifiedOn { get; set; }
    }
```

And here conversation class

```
public class Conversation
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ConversationMember> ConversationMembers { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ConversationMessage> ConversationMessages { get; set; }


    [Required]
    public DateTime LastModifiedOn { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Could you add you ConversationMembers class code ?

Comment: Hey, could you give some sample code to go with it ? Because without knowing how you designed everything is just throwing rocks down a well and hoping it works. Could you also try and write it in FluentApi Syntax ? It is much more readable, especially here.

Comment: @SebastianHofmann I know, I deleted my comment seconds after posting it. I Didn't count the brackets. My bad.

Comment: Could you put your classes to be more clear, what is related with what

Comment: Where does `LastModifiedOn` live?

Comment: @Antry  i added all details now

Comment: Change .Select().LastViewedOn to .Single().LastViewedOn

Comment: @bthn Are you using [Entity Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/) in your project ? It really feels like it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your LINQ to this:

```
.Count(x => x.ConversationMembers.Where(y => y.MembershipId.Value == membershipId)
    .Any(y => y.LastViewedOn == null) || x.ConversationMessages.OrderByDescending(message => message.LastModifiedOn)
    .Any(z => z.LastModifiedOn > x.ConversationMembers.FirstOrDefault(y => y.MembershipId.Value == membershipId).LastViewedOn.Value));
```

Comment: You can make code block by putting 4 spaces at the start of each line instead of using all those back quotes ! :p

Comment: Hmm? I only used one set of back quotes to create the code block. lol

Comment: Oh :o `cause` I `see` the `blocks` `like this` :p

Comment: @trix0412 This works fine after i just changed Single to FirstOrDefault. Thank you so much!